# While Creating React App I get This type of error?

Tags: reactjs

npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/npm/-/npm-8.15.1.tgz - not_found

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404  'npm@https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/npm/-/npm-8.15.1.tgz' is not in this registry.

npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Comment: Maybe remove lock file and try again

Comment: which lock file??

Comment: package-lock.json

Comment: would you show the actual command you're issuing? Also - node & npm versions...

Comment: node -v
v16.16.0 npm -v
8.11.0                  npx create-react-app amazon-clone